# Meaning of minOccurs and maxOccurs for xsd:choice?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

What is the difference between:

```
  <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <element ref="test:A" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </choice>
```

And:

```
  <choice maxOccurs="1">
    <element ref="test:A" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </choice>
```

For any practical purpose?

Comment: Actually, the question is valid for any maxOccurs value between 1 and unbounded,

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in that particular combination.  Choosing a single alternative an unbounded number of times is the same as choosing once to allow an unbounded number of a single alternative.

### How to Think of `xsd:choice` Cardinality

When `@minOccurs` or `@maxOccurs` appear on `xs:choice`, the minimum or maximum number of times the number of *choices* among the alternatives is constrained.

***Then***, for each such choice, the cardinality of the *chosen* child alternative comes into play.

### Example Combinations

The following are some examples expressed in regular expression notation.  Examples of valid sequences for the given combination are also provided.

```
<choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</choice>
```

**Regex**: `[AB]`

Valid sequences include:

- A
- B

---

```
<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</choice>
```

**Regex**: `[AB]?`

Valid sequences include:

- *nothing*
- A
- B

---

```
<choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</choice>
```

**Regex**: `[AB]+`

Valid sequences include:

- *any combination containing at least one A or one B*

---

```
<choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</choice>
```

**Regex**: `A+|B+`

Valid sequences include:

- A
- AA
- AAA
- *etc*
- B
- BB
- BBB
- *etc*

---

```
<choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</choice>
```

**Regex**: `A?|B*`

Valid sequences include:

- *nothing*
- A
- B
- BB
- BBB
- *etc*

---

```
<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</choice>
```

Or

```
<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</choice>
```

Or

```
<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</choice>
```

Etc

**Regex**: `[AB]*`

Valid sequences include:

- *nothing*
- *any combination containing at least one A or one B*

---

### Default Values

The default value for both `@minOccurs` and `@maxOccurs` is 1.

Comment: Excellent. One thing I'd like to add to this: repeatable choices and sequences often cause problems with tools like JAXB. So I generally advise not to use them in schemas.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, in that particular case, but the difference shows up when you add alternatives to the choice:

```
<choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <element ref="test:A" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <element ref="test:B" maxOccurs="1"/>
</choice>
```

would allow any number of A and B elements in any order, whereas

```
<choice maxOccurs="1">
  <element ref="test:A" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <element ref="test:B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</choice>
```

allows any number of As or any number of Bs but not a mixture of the two.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my understanding. But then how come I get an error from this restriction:

Comment: `<complexType name="cxT1">
      <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element ref="test:A" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </choice>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="cxT2">
    <complexContent>
      <restriction base="test:cxT1">
        <choice maxOccurs="1">
          <element ref="test:A" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </choice>
      </restriction>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>`

Comment: (sorry for the formatting). I get an org.xml.sax.SAXParseException for this "Error for type 'cxT2'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base."

Comment: The language accepted by the restricted type is included in the larger language accepted by the original type (A{1,2} from cxT2 is accepted in [A]+ from cxT1)