# The difference between <all> <sequence> <choice> and <group> in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

What is the difference between `<all>  <sequence> <choice> and <group>` in XML Schema?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When to use `xsd:all`, `xsd:sequence`, `xsd:choice`, or `xsd:group`:

- Use `xsd:all` when all child elements must be present, independent of
  order.
- Use `xsd:sequence` when child elements must be present per their
  occurrence constraints and order does matters.
- Use `xsd:choice` when one of the child element must be present.
- Use `xsd:group` as a way to wrap any of the above in order to name
  and reuse in multiple locations within an XSD.

---

Note that occurrence constraints can appear on `xsd:all`, `xsd:sequence`, or `xsd:choice` in addition to the child elements to achieve various cardinality effects.

For example, if `minOccurs="0"` were added to `xsd:element` children of `xsd:all`, element order would be insignificant, but not all child elements would have to be present:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="r">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

For the above XSD, the following XML would be valid, even though not *all* children of `r` are present:

```
<r>
  <b/>
  <a/>
</r>
```

---

### See also

- [Meaning of minOccurs and maxOccurs for xsd:choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28523597/290085)
- [How do I make a group of elements all optional in an XSD (ie. minOccurs="0")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256604/290085)
- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)

Comment: I want to use xsd:all since I don't want to maintain the sequence, but it requires all child elements to be present. I do not want this constraint too. Any way for this?

Comment: @HrishikeshBawane: Add `minOccurs="0"` to those `xsd:element` children of `xsd:all` that you wish to be optional.  I've updated the answer with an example showing how.