# Must a default XML Sequence (or All) with optional child elements have at least one child?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would be grateful if someone could confirm if the interpretation of the following schema is correct:

```
<xs:element name="Element1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child1" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Child2" minOccurs="0" /> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Although both `Child1` and `Child2` are optional, `Element1` has to have at least one child to comply with the above schema; i.e. the document:

```
<Element1></Element1>
```

Would not comply. For this to be valid, it would require sequence `minOccurs = 0`(?)

**Update**

The question relates to the meaning of occurrence for sequence (and all) when child elements are optional. For example, the document;

```
<Element1>
    <Child2/>
    <Child1/>
</Element1>
```

Would comply with the above schema. The sequence would have occurred twice; in the first pass, `Child1` was absent. In the second, `Child2` was absent. But the point is, the sequence `minOccurs` (default of 1) was satisfied, because it occurred twice.

With the first example I gave above (just `Element1`; no child elements), sequence does not occur at all, and does not (IMO) satisfy `minOccurs = 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Must a default XML Sequence (or All) with optional child elements have at least one child?

No...

> Although both `Child1` and `Child2` are optional, `Element1` has to have at
>   least one child to comply with the above schema

The default value for `minOccurs` is `1`, so you're correct to assume that the `xsd:sequence` is constrained to appear once.  However, `xsd:sequence minOccurs="1"` is satisfied as long as its children's occurrence constraints are satisfied once.  When all child occurrence constraints are `minOccurs="0"`, one empty sequence is allowed. 
 Therefore,  `<Element1/>` is valid, even without any `Child1` or `Child2` children elements.

**See also**

- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821477/xml-schema-minoccurs-maxoccurs-default-values)
- [The difference between <all> <sequence> <choice> and <group> in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286056/the-difference-between-all-sequence-choice-and-group-in-xsd)

---

### Further examples:

**XSD with `xs:sequence minOccurs="0"`**

```
<xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="a"/>
            <xs:element name="b"/> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**Valid XML:** `<r/>` and `<r><a/><b/></r>`

**XSD with `xs:sequence minOccurs="1"` (default)**

```
<xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="a"/>
            <xs:element name="b"/> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**Valid XML:** `<r><a/><b/></r>`

**XSD with `xs:sequence minOccurs="2"`**

```
<xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
            <xs:element name="a"/>
            <xs:element name="b"/> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**Valid XML:** `<r><a/><b/><a/><b/></r>`