# Allow sequence OR empty in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Looking to figure out how to match either on a set sequence *or* no value. Example below of my sequence, but I'm stuck for how to get it to accept *either* the sequence as written, or the `<body>` tag existing with no value inside it.

```xml
<xs:element name="body">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id"   type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want the above to match on either a blank (as below) or a correctly filled tag.

`<body></body>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `minOccurs="0"` to `xs:sequence` to allow the entire sequence to be optional.

### See also

- [Must a default XML Sequence (or All) with optional child elements have at least one child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46942790/290085)
- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)

Comment: Woo! That's perfect! I was searching on the wrong keywords before :)