# Refer to specific element of an XSD model group?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Can we create a group and refer to element of that group?

For example, we have a group say

```
<xs:group name="custGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Address1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Address2" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="mobile" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Suppose I want to create another element to have only `customerId` and `mobile`:

```
<xs:element name="custBrief">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="mobile" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

So, I should be able to refer to `custGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Re-use parts of your group by declaring the constituent elements by reference rather than by name:

```
<xs:group name="custGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="customerId"/>
    <xs:element ref="customerName"/>
    <xs:element ref="Address1"/>
    <xs:element ref="Address2"/>
    <xs:element ref="mobile"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Address1" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Address2" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="mobile" type="xs:string"/>
```

This way, your second, similar group can at least share the global declarations of the referenced elements:

```
<xs:element name="custBrief">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="customerId"/>
    <xs:element ref="mobile"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

**Option 2:** Use subgroups:

```
<xs:group name="custGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="custBriefGroup"/>
    <xs:element ref="customerName"/>
    <xs:element ref="Address1"/>
    <xs:element ref="Address2"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="custBriefGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="mobile" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="custBrief">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="custBriefGroup"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

This way, `custBriefGroup` is defined in one place an re-used.

Note that I took liberties with re-arranging element ordering.

See also: [The difference between <all> <sequence> <choice> and <group> in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286056/the-difference-between-all-sequence-choice-and-group-in-xsd)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different schema construction models here.

You can assemble a type from a set of building blocks by using model groups.

You can "subset" a type by using derivation-by-restriction.

But you can't mix the two in the way you are attempting.