# How do I make a group of elements all optional in an XSD (ie. minOccurs="0")?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Is there an easier way to make a group of elements under a complex tag optional in an XSD? (ie, `minOccurs` for each should be `0`)? Currently, I am adding a `minOccurs="0"` individually to each element.

Furthermore, is there any way to set/change the default cardinality of `minOccurs="1"` to `minOccurs="0"` for all elements that I define in my schema?

Answer (score 1):

> Furthermore, is there any way to set/change the default cardinality of `minOccurs="1"` to `minOccurs="0"` for all elements that I define in my schema?

No, there is not.

> Currently, I am adding a `minOccurs="0"` individually to each element.

This is exactly what you should be doing.

> Is there an easier way to make a group of elements under a complex tag optional in an XSD? (ie, `minOccurs` for each should be `0`)?

Yes, but realize that the meaning of the setting is such that it applies to the semantics of the model group.  For example, for `xs:sequence`,

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
  <xsl:element name="a"/>
  <xsl:element name="b"/>
  <xsl:element name="c"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

means that the sequence, *collectively*, is optional – ***not*** that each element is *individually* optional.

For `xs:choice`,

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0">
  <xsl:element name="a"/>
  <xsl:element name="b"/>
  <xsl:element name="c"/>
</xs:choice>
```

means that the choice between `a`, `b`, and `c` itself is optional (you may choose zero or one of them) – again, ***not*** that each element is *individually* optional.