# What is the difference between <xs:group> and <xs:attributeGroup>?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'd like to understand the difference and use cases of each group type.

I've seen [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp) in W3 schools, and it wasn't clear when to use either.

Comment: W3Schools can sometimes be a handy source of reference information and sometimes it can be dreadful. I'd put the page you cite in the second category. It collects a random set of concepts together under an invented heading "indicators" which is not used in the spec (and is therefore never going to appear in an error message), and it doesn't explain any of them in enough detail to actually use them. To use XSD, in my view, you need to buy a couple of good books.

Answer (score 3):

XSD [`xs:group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cModel_Group_Definitions) and [`xs:attributeGroup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAttribute_Group_Definitions) enable declaration reuse in `xs:complexType` definitions:

- Use `xs:group` to define a named, reusable group of ***elements***.
- Use `xs:attributeGroup` to define a named, reusable group of ***attributes***.

See [W3C XML Schema Part 0: Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) for [`xs:group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#groups) and [`xs:attributeGroup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#AttrGroups) examples.

### See also

- [The difference between <all> <sequence> <choice> and <group> in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36286056/290085)