# cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'X'. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xmlschema

> `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d`: Invalid content was found starting with element `wydane`. No child element is expected at this point.

I do not know what I could do to solve this problem.
Someone have any idea?

Below is a fragment of my XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="nazwa" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="wydane" type="xs:string"/>
    
    
    <xs:element name="dlc">
        <xs:complexType mixed="false">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="wydane"/>
                    <xs:element ref="nazwa"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="rodzaj" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Below is a frament of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hobby xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlschema2.xsd">
   <gry>
        <strategiczne>
            <HeartsOfIron4 gatunek="RTS,GSW">
            <studio premiera="06.06.2016">Pradadox Interactive</studio>
                <dlc rodzaj="PayToPlay">
                <nazwa>By blood alone</nazwa>
                <wydane>2022.09.27</wydane>
                <nazwa>No step back</nazwa>
                <wydane>2021.11.23</wydane>
                <nazwa>Battle for the Bosporus</nazwa>
                <wydane>2020.10.15</wydane>
                <nazwa>La Resistance</nazwa>
                <wydane>2022.02.25</wydane>
                <nazwa>Man the Gun</nazwa>
                <wydane>2019.02.28</wydane>
                <nazwa>Waking the Tiger</nazwa>
                <wydane>2018.03.08</wydane>
                <nazwa>Death or Dishonor</nazwa>
                <wydane>2017.06.14</wydane>
                <nazwa>Together for Victory</nazwa>
                <wydane>2016.12.15</wydane>
                </dlc>
```

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please accept the answer that helped.  If not, please follow-up and explain what else you need to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSD says that `dlc` can have a choice of either one `wydane` element *or* one `nazwa` element, yet your XML tries to repeat those elements.  Upon the first repetition, you receive the stated error.

If you wish `dlc` to have that choice repeated, then add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the `xsd:choice` element.

If you wish `dlc` content to be an ordered pairs of `wydane` and `nazwa` elements, then change `xsd:choice` to `xsd:sequence`, and again add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the `xsd:sequence` element.

### See also

- [Meaning of minOccurs and maxOccurs for xsd:choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28523597/290085)
- [minOccurs/maxOccurs on xsd:sequence vs xsd:element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74056858/290085)
- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)